# Capturando exceção de rotas no express

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express.js

Escrevo uma aplicação com Express e Typescript, e para capturar as exceções das rotas faço assim:

index.ts

```js
// ...
app.use(userRoutes);
app.use(handleError);
// ...
```

tendo 'handleError' em um arquivo separado:

```js
export function handleError(
  err: Error,
  req: Request,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) {
  return res.status(500).json(err);
}
```

até ai tudo bem, porém erros vindos de funções assíncronas há uma solução de criar um embrulho em cima da função do controller na rota:

```js
// ...
router.get("/users", wrapAsync(getUsers));
router.get("/users/:id", wrapAsync(getUser));
router.post("/users", wrapAsync(createUser));
// ...
```

```
export function wrapAsync(fn: RequestHandler) {
  return function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
  };
}
```

A pergunta é: **vou ter que embrulhar todos os métodos do controller para capturar de forma geral seus erros assíncronos ou há algum meio sem ter que embrulhar todas as minhas rotas?**

Comment: Se você estiver usando o Express "puro", sim, é a única forma de fazê-lo, já que essa biblioteca não suporta captura de erros "assíncronos" por padrão.

Comment: voce usa o try/catch nos codigos do controllers? porque eu sempre uso ele para sempre que houver um erro, async ou nao, eu passo o erro como parametro no next ( next(err) ) e tenho uma funcao semelhante a sua `handleError` para tratar seja qual for o erro, pra nao ter que ficar uasndo `wrapAsync` em todas as rotas. nao sei se isso pode te ajudar.

Comment: obrigado, ambas as respostas foram de extrema importância